# How can my app be suggested by Microsoft Edge?

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge, windows-store

Microsoft Edge suggest apps from store on new tab page. For example Twitter, Facebook, Instagram. 
How can I link my site with store app? I supposed that it may be linked with [web-to app linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking), however not Twitter nor Instagram has implemented this in manifest inside app or windows-app-web-link file on server.

So, once again, how can I link my site with my app?

[image]

Comment: "Microsoft Edge suggest apps from store on new tab page.".... not here... I think that may be just an experiment by MS marketing.

Comment: @RobParsons it's there for a while